# PHP calling a method from outside another class

Tags: php, oop

Not sure of OOP syntax to do this...
I'd like to have aclass that calls the mysqli object

```
class Voovid_DB {
    private $host = 'localhost';
    private $user = 'blahblah';
    private $password = 'blahblah';
    private $name = 'blahblah';

    public function __contstuct(){
        $dbh= new mysqli( $this->host, $this->user, $this->password, $this->name );
        return $dbh;
    }

     //get and set methods for host, user etc... go here    
}
```

now I'd like to access all the mysqli methods like so

```
$dbconnect = new Voovid_DB();
if ( $result = $dbconnect->query( "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM members WHERE member_id=9" ) ) {
    while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
        $first_name = ucfirst( $row['first_name'] );
        $last_name = ucfirst( $row['last_name'] );
    }
} else {
    $errors = $dbconnect->error;
}
```

i'm new to PHP OOP and not sure how to get to the mysqli methods inside the Voovid_DB class

Comment: You misspelled "__construct". Is it misspelled in your program? If so, you'd have to call it like any other function.

Answer (score 2):

You have to either extend the MySQLi class, or build a proxy around it.

The easiest is probably to extend it:

```
class Voovid_DB extends MySQLi {
    private $host = 'localhost';
    private $user = 'blahblah';
    private $password = 'blahblah';
    private $name = 'blahblah';

    public function __construct(){
        // call parent (MySQLi) constructor
        parent::__construct( $this->host, $this->user, $this->password, $this->name );
    }

    // no need for other methods, they already are there
}
```

Notice the `extends MySQLi`.

Then your second code snipet should work.

Or, build a proxy:

```
class Voovid_DB {
    private $host = 'localhost';
    private $user = 'blahblah';
    private $password = 'blahblah';
    private $name = 'blahblah';
    private $dbh;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->dbh = new MySQLi($this->host, $this->user, $this->password, $this->name);
    }

    // this will proxy any calls to this class to MySQLi
    public function __call($name, $args) {
        return call_user_func_array(array($this->dbh,$name), $args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a `__call` method:

```
public function __call($method, $arguments) {
    return call_user_func_array(array($this->dbh, $method), $arguments);
}
```

`__call` is invoked if an undefined or inivisible method is called.

Answer (score 0):

you code is correct.

the only thing you have to do is to make sure that you define your functions in Voovid_DB as public.

private or protected methods cannot be accessed from other classes

store your mysqli object in a public field in your class then you can access it like this:

```
$dbconnect->mysqlField->query
```

Answer (score 0):

Constructors aren't supposed to return anything. When you say `$dbconnect = new Voovid_DB();` you would normally be trying to create a Voovid_DB object, but it looks like you're using it to try an make a mysqli object. Don't make this the constructor and call the function after you create the voovid_db object.

```
$obj = new voovid_DB();
$dbConnect = $obj->createMysqli();
```